# "wait for concurrent gc blocked" issue when starting the android emulator

Tags: android

I have downloaded the ADT bundle from android developer site and trying to start the emulator. But most of the time it is getting stuck in the starting process and other times it takes 5-10 mins to start.

I have checked the LOGCAT and there is this msg repeatedly coming : "**wait for concurrent gc blocked**"

Do anyone know how to solve this issue and and start the emulator normally?

Please note that I have a laptop with decent specs and I am not deploying any app in the emulator... I am just starting it plain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Messages like this:

```
dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 6ms
```

indicate that thread A performed an allocation that couldn't be satisfied, so it tried to collect garbage.  It discovered that a concurrent GC was already in progress in thread B, so it had to wait for that to finish.

Seeing a lot of those messages just means there's a lot of memory churn in that process.  It also indicates that the system isn't simply stuck.

If you use

```
adb shell ps
```

and search for the process ID shown in the log message (use `adb logcat -v threadtime`), you can see what process is spinning.

Answer (score 1):

you have infinite loops. track your looping canditions from the beginning